# Open all routes, for testing purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

As a very basic form of testing (or sanity check), I'd like as a step of my build process to open all routes in my app (specifying parameters if necessary and providing a logged in user), and check which ones raise e.g. an HTTP 500 error.

Is this a common practice? Does any library/facility provide it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a library, but it is common practice in some cases (depending on the number of test cases it results in).

It is called exhaustive testing.